# CSV file is not downloading in cakephp

Tags: php, csv, cakephp

I am new in cakephp framework.I want to generate csv file.Here I have result array like :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [username] => yerica
                [email] => amoreyerica@gmail.com
                [phone] => 993643636
            )

        [DealPurchase] => Array
            (
                [deal_title] => Tour de Zaragoza
                [original_price] => 30
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [username] => Rama Test
                [email] => rama@gmail.com
                [phone] => 9652369854
            )

        [DealPurchase] => Array
            (
                [deal_title] => Tour de Zaragoza
                [original_price] => 30
            )

    )

)
```

Here, I want to generate csv of this array.

Here, I have include CsvHelper.php file in view/helpers folder.This file contains :

```
 <?php
  class CsvHelper extends AppHelper
  {
     var $delimiter = ',';
     var $enclosure = '"';
     var $filename = 'Export.csv';
     var $line = array();
     var $buffer;

     function CsvHelper()
     {
        $this->clear();
     }
     function clear() 
     {
        $this->line = array();
        $this->buffer = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:'. (5*1024*1024), 'r+');
     }

     function addField($value) 
     {
        $this->line[] = $value;
     }

     function endRow() 
     {
        $this->addRow($this->line);
        $this->line = array();
     }

     function addRow($row) 
     {
       fputcsv($this->buffer, $row, $this->delimiter, $this->enclosure);
     }

     function renderHeaders() 
     {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition:attachment;filename=".$this->filename);
     }

     function setFilename($filename) 
     {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        if (strtolower(substr($this->filename, -4)) != '.csv') 
        {
            $this->filename .= '.csv';
        }
     }

     function render($outputHeaders = true, $to_encoding = null, $from_encoding ="auto") 
    {
      if ($outputHeaders) 
      {
        if (is_string($outputHeaders)) 
        {
           $this->setFilename($outputHeaders);
        }
        $this->renderHeaders();
      }
      rewind($this->buffer);
      $output = stream_get_contents($this->buffer);

     if ($to_encoding) 
     {
       $output = mb_convert_encoding($output, $to_encoding, $from_encoding);
     }
     return $this->output($output);
   }
}
?>
```

In MerchantController(controller) function is looks like :

```
function download_csv($deal_id)
{           
    $options=array('fields'=>'User.username,User.email,User.phone,DealPurchase.deal_title,DealPurchase.original_price',
                    'joins' =>
                              array(
                                array(
                                    'table' => 'deal_purchases',
                                    'alias' => 'DealPurchase',
                                    'type' => 'inner',
                                    'foreignKey' => false,
                                    'conditions'=> array('DealPurchase.user_id = User.id')
                                )));

          $this->recursive = -1;
          $data = $this->User->find('all', $options);

         $this->set("users",$data);
         $this->layout = null;
         $this->autoLayout = false;
         Configure::write('debug', '0');

    }
```

Here,My view file code is :

```
<?php
$line= $users[0]['User'];
$this->CSV->addRow(array_keys($line));
foreach ($users as $user)
{
   $line = $user['User'];
   $this->CSV->addRow($line);
}
$filename='users';
echo  $this->CSV->render($filename);
```

Here, my another function which contains link of download csv file and function looks like :

```
function deal_list(){            
        $this->_checkMerchantSession();
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Deal List');
        $this->layout = "after_login";
        //echo $this->Session->read('userData.Merchant.id');
        //$conditions = "Deal.merchant_id ='".$this->Session->read('userData.Merchant.id')."' AND Deal.isdeleted ='0' AND Deal.isapproved ='0' ";
        $conditions = "Deal.merchant_id ='".$this->Session->read('userData.Merchant.id')."' AND Deal.isdeleted ='0' ";

        //$ArDealdetails = $this->Deal->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions,'order'=>'Deal.modified DESC'));
        $this->paginate = array('conditions' => $conditions,'limit' =>5,'order'=>'Deal.id DESC');
        $ArDealdetails = $this->paginate('Deal');
        $this->set('ArDealdetails',$ArDealdetails);    

        $condition1 = "Merchant.id ='".$this->Session->read('userData.Merchant.id')."'";
        $merchant_detail = $this->Merchant->find('first',array('conditions'=>$condition1)); 
        $this->set('merchant_detail',$merchant_detail);        
    }
```

Now, when I include helper as Csv like:

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Javascript','Fck','Js','Paginator','Csv');
```

Then it will gives an error.So how can I resolve this problem?

**Note :** I have an error like : **Error: The requested address '/merchant/deal_list' was not found on this server.** I have added download csv link in deal_list view file. When I remove **Csv** from the helpers then this page is display.

**Error:** Undefined property: View::$Csv.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @JasonJoslin see my updated question in Note.

Comment: Do you have a deal_list() action in your merchant controller? what does it look like?

Comment: Yes I have deal_list() in merchant controller.

Comment: @JasonJoslin I have write deal_list() in my question.

Comment: Not the answer to your questions, not sure if you have cut it off or it isnt there. `deal_list()` and `download_csv()` should be public e.g (`public function deal_list()`)

Comment: @JasonJoslin I have tried but its not working.

Comment: I guess you have some other error. Turn on debug and show us the actual error you get

Comment: you are using a layout named "after_login". If it contains some text (and I guess it does) then you are sending csv headers after it and it causes an error. You have to use an empty layout.

Comment: @arilia I have used null layout in download_csv()

Comment: @arilia Should I have to write **Configure::write('debug', '1');** to on debug mode?

Comment: I guess you're using cake 2 (but you forgot to mention it in your question) so `Configure::write('debug', 2)`

Comment: @arilia check error that i have write in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have just rename **CsvHelper.php** helper file to **csv.php** so its working. So can anybody explain me why its working because of **csv.php** name?

Comment: something it's wrong. Should be CsvHelper.php.  see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)

Comment: @arilia yeah, but now its working i don't know why. But, when i used CsvHelper.php then it shows an error like **Undefined property: View::$Csv.**

Comment: what version of cake are you using?

Comment: well, so it's right. Remember to always cite your exact cakephp version. I was guessing you were using cake 2. If you had mentioned your version we would have found the error before

Comment: @arilia Ok, sorry for that.But how helper file name affect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109998/discussion-between-nisarg-and-arilia).

Answer (score 0):

Casing is wrong on your csv helpers in the view. Should be `$this->Csv`

```
<?php
$line= $users[0]['User'];
$this->Csv->addRow(array_keys($line));
foreach ($users as $user)
{
   $line = $user['User'];
   $this->Csv->addRow($line);
}
$filename='users';
echo  $this->Csv->render($filename);
```

Comment: In helper file where I have to change? because am not aware about it its new for me.

Comment: I dont even know if it is the full answer to your questions. just noticed it is not right. 

not in the helper. in the view. see my edit.

Comment: Ok, that I have chnaged.But still its not working.I have tried another method but its not working.

Comment: At this point what exactly doesnt work? are there any error messages? does the method output() exist? couldn't see it in the csv helper yet render() makes a call to it. 'return $this->output($output)'